# Python: How to return maximum value related to a string from a table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, openpyxl

I have a problem where I need to find the maximum value related to a string. The data is stored in excel.
I understand I need to use openpyxl and possibly pandas. Example below:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| x | 10 |
| x | 5 |
| x | 1 |
| y | 40 |
| y | 11 |
| y | 101 |
| z | 30 |
| z | 31 |

I am looking for the following output:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| x | 10 |
| y | 101 |
| z | 31 |

Here is the beginning of my code:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Book1.xlsx")
sh1=wb['Sheet1']

import pandas as pd
excel_file= pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Book1.xlsx")
def = excel_file.parse(excel_file.sheet_nams[0])
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: You lost me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: find the maximum value for each string from column 1 , so for x, I want the code to search column 2 and return the max value: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
out = df.groupby('Name').max().reset_index()
```

Or

```
out = df.sort_values('Value').drop_duplicates('Name',keep='last').sort_index()
  Name  Value
0    x     10
5    y    101
7    z     31
```

Comment: Thank you! this works! How can I now print 'out' back into another sheet? assuming that there is sh2 ?

Comment: @user11427018 https://stackoverflow.com/a/35708411/7964527

Answer (score 0):

Pandas can do all of this natively. By adding in @BENY's answer, we can do it easily.

```
import pandas as pd
grp = pd.read_excel("C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Book1.xlsx").groupby('Name').max().reset_index()

for i in grp:
    print(i)
```